# rails save static page url in database with other data, then fetch result and wrap result with that url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

how to figure this out. i building a travel application in which i will save data about many places, which have attributes like its name, short description, price,etc. also i like to save a url pointing to its static page which will have more information about that place.

since i am want to show detailed information(historical,culture,transit info,etc) about the place, thats y choosing to create a static page.

now, when a user does a search using certain parameters, i like to load the result wrapped with its static page url in the show page.

now, how can this be done. and more importantly, is this a good way?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a broad question so I hope I can answer it the right way. Assuming you're storing the data in a DB I would have a resource controller for that data e.g.:

DB tbl:

```
Place
- name (String:255)
- description (String:255)
- price (String:255)
- ...etc...
```

You would then have a controller places_controller for example with an index method that would take parameters on what you would like to search on. So the user would be able to build a build a URL using a form such as: ://localhost:3000/places?q=new%20york

And then use a gem as Ransack, you can read all about it here: https://github.com/ernie/ransack

So once you have the right records it's just a matter of rendering these on the index, you're index could look something like this:

```
Search results:
<ul>
 <% @places.each do |place| %>
   <li>
     <%= link_to place.name, places_url(place) %>
   </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

the place_url is a method provided by Rails but you could replace this with a method in your helper which would either generate the static page url. Or you could render the static page url as a attribute e.g. `link_to place.name, place.static_url`

HTH,

Comment: i do have a form where search is performed through select box, where params are filtered to display the various places. now, first thing is what should the url be like when i store it alongside other data. full url to its static page?? also, when the results are shown, the place would have its name, short description, price, etc. all that needs to be wrapped with that url. how can i do this?

Comment: Ok, so you have the static page? What does the url to that look like and why would you need the params. What do you mean by wrapping it?

Comment: the url wud be like - places/new-york. i told u about the params coz the user sees a form which has a select box populated with categories, to filter results with their choice. now, when the result is shown(containing place name, short description, price,etc), i like to put that in a div and make it into a link, pointing to its static page url, so that they can view detailed info about those places. that url, i guess needs to be stored alongside other data about the place in the db.

Comment: so two things. first, what shud be the url like while storing it in the db? second, how to wrap a div with link_to which points to its static page?

Comment: That is completely dependent on how the static page is being generated and served up by the webserver, how are you doing? Alternatively you can look into not making this static and using caching to help ease the pain on db intensive pages: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: okay, if i created a static page about new york and i am creating a row about new york, what am i suppose to input as the url, so that if the category matches while user adjust parameters, succinct data about new york is wrapped with that static page url.